# fprintf exercise working but the txt is not valid after running

Tags: c, file, text, printf, corruption

I'm having a problem I can't tell what to do. I have this task that asks me to take the words from a file (let's say input.txt) and write them all in another file (let's say output.txt) in the reverse order. The fun part is that when I execute my program (I have a VM of Xubuntu given to me from my University) it's impossible to double click the output.txt file 'cause something's wrong: I'll try to translate it: 
"Byte sequence invalid in the conversion's input"

The fun part is that if I do "gedit output.txt" I do see those words all well written how they should be, so I'd say my program "works but corrupts the file". What can be the theoreticals reasons behind this? And if you wanna help me out pointing them, here's a link to my code [EDIT, it seems I can't post the pastebin link. Here's the part that involves the output file]:

```
    `char *t=malloc(sizeof(char)*1025), *tmp;
     t=fgets(t,1024,fp);

     while(t!=NULL){
         tmp=strtok(t, " ");
         while(tmp!=NULL){  
             tmp=strrev(tmp);
             fprintf(fo, " %s", tmp);
             tmp=strtok(NULL, " ");
         }
     t=fgets(t,1024,fp);
     }`
```

I hope I didn't break any rule 'cause I'm still new to this site, thanks all!

Comment: Post the code along with your question instead of a link to it.

Comment: Yes, you broke a rule. Don't link your code.

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't get the first two comments, they do seem contradictory to me. I didn't post it without the link because even if it's not the longest code ever written it's still kind of a long portion and I thought it'd be bad to see. I guess I'll edit the part I think matters..
@Someprogrammerdude thanks for the links, I'll read 'em asap

Comment: The purpose of an MVCE code is that we can copy/paste your code and see by yourself what's going on. I don't think I can compile your code ... Also, there is a flaw in your algorithm : what happen if there is the word "problem" at the index 1022 ? the first fgets will have "pr" and you will write "rp" in the outpout file, and the second fgets will have "oblem" and you will write "melbo", ending up with "rpmelbo" instead of "melborp".

Comment: So should I post the whole code? It's kind of weird. Anyway it's all on the assumptions our teacher gave to us, the line won't be longer than that that's why I use a limited read. I forgot to mention it in the beginning expecially because I've posted the pastebin link with the whole code buuut it seems I can't :/ In case you're wondering, fp = input and fo = output, plus I had to use strtok and fgets

Comment: You should post a minimal code, because when you will "strip away" the irrevelant code part in order to make the minimal one, you can magically make your program "work", and that can lead to the solution.
Your pastebin code can be considered minimal, by the way.

Comment: Well I guess the part that I've put is enough because the rest of the program is literally just testing I'm in the assumptions my task asked me I had to be in (argc = 3 or argc = 4, checking that input file is present and other stuff). After that there's simply the usual fclose(fo&fp) aaand that's it. Anyway I have to point out that strrev isn't present in Linux as far as I know so I reimplemented it simply copying the last character of the string in the first one and viceversa. Could it be it?

Comment: what part of "we should be able to copy/paste your code and compile it" did you miss ????  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seem there is not a problem with your code itself.

Can you test this and say if your problem is here again ?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strrev(char *str)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = strlen(str) - 1;

    while (i < j) {
        char tmp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[j];
        str[j] = tmp;
        ++i;
        --j;
    }
  return (str);
}

#define BUFFER_LEN 1024

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char line[BUFFER_LEN + 1];
    FILE *fp                  = NULL;
    FILE *fo                  = NULL;

    if (argc != 3 && argc != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Devi usare 2 o 3 argomenti grz\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (!(fp = fopen(argv[1],"r"))) { //argv1=input.txt
        fprintf(stderr, "Devi \n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (!(fo = fopen(argv[2], (argc == 4 && strcmp(argv[3],"a")) ? "a" : "w"))) {
        fprintf(stderr, " 3 argomenti grz\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while(fgets(line, BUFFER_LEN, fp)) {
        for (char *word = strtok(line, " "); word; word = strtok(NULL, " ")) {
            fprintf(fo, "%s ", strrev(word));
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fo);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Can you compile & run this code and say if "mousepad" is still losing himself ?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE *fo = NULL;

    if (argc != 3 && argc != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Devi usare 2 o 3 argomenti grz\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (!(fo = fopen(argv[2], "w"))) {
        fprintf(stderr, " 3 argomenti grz\n");
        return -1;
    }

    fprintf(fo, "test");


    fclose(fo);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah it still says the same thing when I try to double click the output.txt file. But again if I use "gedit" on that same file that I'm not able to double-click, I can see all the words in the correct order. Any idea? Because it's been 3 days straight I'm into this and I'm going insane :(

Comment: double-click ? What's the program openning your result file ? Because if your file is considered like an executable, I think that can be the error. Especially if you can open your file with gedit like a charm.

Comment: I'm ready to screenshot it if i needed, anyway it says "Mousepad". This same "Mousepad" can open the "input.txt" file without an issue tho

Comment: Wait. I just got it. The problem is that it tries to open it with the option "System(UTF-8)". If I remove the "è" word from the input.txt file (which is the word "is" in italian) I'm finally able to open it even with double-click. Woah.. Thanks anyway, you made me realize that!

Comment: So mousepad is the problem, not your code. Glad for you those 3 day of suffering came to an end. Good luck !